# Should this be a lone Model, a Model and Controller, or some other Ruby class entirely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, model-view-controller

Currently in my app a `QuoteRequest` `has_one` `Quote` which `belongs_to` a `QuoteRequest`. QuoteRequest has full MVC, i.e. `QuoteRequest#new` view enables user to create and persist the object and its data to a QuoteRequest table in the db.

I'm now working out how to design the next stage, that should be;

- when a QuoteRequest is created it should kick off the application crawling to an external site
- crawling and scraping to get the quote results using the QuoteRequest data, persisting that result to the app’s db.
- then rendering a view of that persisted quote data.

As a newbie I’m struggling to decide how best to design and write this. I believe I understand the general MVC standard, of a C serving the user a V, that V capturing something from the user and the C then taking that something and sending it to the M to persist it into the db. But I'm not unsure how anything other than something with this defined MVC relationship would fit into the Rails environment.

In my next stage after QuoteRequest is created there’s a part of the process that doesn’t need a view, ie once the QuoteRequest data is persisted to the db it needs to kick off something in the app, currently `Quote` though no functionality written in Quote yet, that goes out
 crawls, scrapes and saves, then we’re back to needing a view for that saved scrape to be rendered.

So I’m wondering whether this ‘non view requiring’ stage of the process ought to be neither a model or a controller, rather some type of standard Ruby class. E.g. flow as below(pls excuse strange 'pseudo code'!):

- On successful `QuoteRequest.save` >> `OtherClass.start_crawl` >> on `OtherClass.crawl_success` >> save as a `Quote.create` (no view) >> `Quote.show(OtherClass.crawl_sucess_result)` view >> Done.

Can anyone help me out with making decisions about how to design this, I guess pretty simple, pattern. Thanks

Comment: Niice ho-man & widjajayd, let me get planning and playing with code off the back of those v helpful suggestions and I'll accept an answer shortly, wish i could accept multiple answers! as both of your contributions are really appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to use your "pseudo code" and combine controller and PORO (plain Old Ruby Object), below some tips for your case

```
class QuoteRequestsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @quote_request = QuoteRequest.new
  end

  def create
    @quote_request = QuoteRequest.new(quote_request_params)
    if @quote_request.save
      flash[:success] = "QuoteRequest successful save"
      # contact other class
      @crawling_service = MyModuleService::Other.new(@quote_request) 
      @crawling_service.start_crawl
      if @crawling_service.crawl_result # if success
        # create your quote
        @quote = @quote_request.create_quote(arg1, arg2, etc)
        @quote.save
        # after save redirect_to quote show
        redirect_to quote_path(@quote)
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = @barang.errors.full_messages[0]
    end
  end
end
```

### create PORO as services in rails

create app/services folder, then you can create one file 
in this folder with name for example my_module_service.rb

```
module MyModuleService
  attr_reader :crawl_result
  class Other
    def initialize(quote_request)
      @quote_request = quote_request
    end

    def start_crawl
      # your start crawl process
      if success
        crawl_result = true 
        # this for send message back whether success or not the crawling
      else
        crawl_result = false
      end


    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As I look at it, I feel like the crawling should be a background task so it doesn't hog up processes.

- Add `after_save` in the QuoteRequest model (or you could also just invoke it in your controller)
- Create an empty `Quote` object perhaps
- Use a background-task library like [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).
- Write a worker ([activejob](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html)) that does the crawl and updates the `Quote` object above with the results.)
- The view of the quote should show that it's processing at the time when it's not yet crawled.